# Angular submit not called when required fields not filled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm creating a form in Angular with Ionic. I don't want a red error class to be displayed unless a user has submitted the form. As such, my code looks like this:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="form">
     <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="data.type" name="type" ng-value="item.value" ng-class="{'error' : form.type.$invalid && formSubmitted }"
</form>
```

And then in my controllers

```
$scope.submit = function ()
{
   $scope.formSubmitted = true; //Tell our errors they can show now
}
```

So the error class should only show up when formSubmitted is true. For whatever reason, however, `required` prevents `submit` from being called. This isn't the case for other attributes such as minlength.

How can I get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `novalidate` to your form.

The reason being, your browser is validating your form rather than letting your code do it.

alternatively, do something like:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="form" novalidate>
     <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="data.type" name="type" ng-value="item.value" ng-class="{'error' : form.type.$invalid && form.$submitted }"
</form>
```

`form.$submitted` will become true when you submit.